# understanding clean up method in react use effect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function IntervalHookCounter() {

    const [count,setcount]=useState(0);
    const tick=()=>{
        setcount(prevcount=>prevcount+1);
    }

    const printHello=()=>{
      console.log("hello");
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        const interval=setInterval(tick,1000);
        return()=>{
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    },[])
  
    return (
    <div>
      {count}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I wrote this component for a timer displaying on page. If I dont use return in use effect the timer is jumping twice at a time why is that so.

and

```
import React, {  useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function IntervalHookCounter() {

    const [count,setcount]=useState(0);
    const tick=()=>{
        setcount(prevcount=>prevcount+1);
        // setcount(count+1);
    }

    const printHello=()=>{
      console.log("hello");
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
      printHello();
        const interval=setInterval(tick,1000);
        return()=>{
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    },[])
  
    return (
    <div>
      {count}
    </div>
  )
}
```

if i write the above code hello is being printed only twice in the console , as count is being changed based on the previous count in the tick method , I think the answer might be I didn't include count in  the use effect [], like i have to put [count] in the use effect array ,
Then how is timer being increased without including count in the [] of use effect,

I am new to react ,confused with the functionality of use effect

I tried to use useeffect function various ways possible i didn't get the output what i expected

Comment: are you using strict mode?

Comment: Hi Dale,  I don't have idea what strict mode is , I have created a js file and write react code in it and run it on vs code.

Comment: in your index.js file you might see some tags like `<React.StrictMode>` and if you so you may want to read [the react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) about what it does to your app, essentially it's doing some extra stuff to your code while in dev mode to help you find issues with state.

Comment: yes I see it's on strict mode
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

Comment: strict mode is the reason it's being printed twice (to force  you to make sure you cleanup correctly), but the reason it's not running again is exactly hat you guessed, because your dependency array is empty so nothing is gonna trigger that effect to run again, from what i see you have a good understanding of useEffect, just missing some details about the dependency array

Comment: got it I removed the strict method now it renders perfectly, I am in learning phase , which one should i prefer using strict mode or ignoring it , please suggest me and also if i didn't include count in the dependency array let's say the dependency array is empty and i am updating count like this setcount(prevcount=>prevcount+1) then what happens?

Comment: my thoughts are like as the count is not included in the dependency array the useeffect method should not be called and the timer should not be increased

Comment: and the last doubt I have is why are we using cleanup method in this case , I see no difference with or without it's presence .

Answer (score 0):

Try to check you component Strictmode,  in general it is writen on index.js
when you use this component,  the useeffect() hook is invoked twice on developement enviroment. here a explanation:
[here](https://blog.bitsrc.io/react-v18-0-useeffect-bug-why-do-effects-run-twice-39babecede93)

`root.render(<React.StrictMode><IntervalHookCounter /> </React.StrictMode>)`

so you can either remove this `<React.StrictMode>` or adjust your component.

Comment: Hi Valter if i didn't include count in the dependency array let's say the dependency array is empty and i am updating count like this setcount(prevcount=>prevcount+1) then what happens?

my thoughts are like as the count is not included in the dependency array the useeffect method should not be called and the timer should not be increased